# process data in a callback function with jquery's .get not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a strange problem with processing data coming back from a php script in javascript.

This is my code:

```
 $.get('status.php', null, resp, 'text');


 function resp(data) {

      console.error(data);

      if(data == 'ready') {

           alert(data);               
      }
 }
```

Now, data definitely contains 'ready' as I can see when I look at the error console (console.error(data); print me 'ready' in the console).

However the if-statement does not return true and therefore the alert statement is not executed.

But why?
I can print data, I can see it is definitely equal to 'ready', yet the statement within the if-statement never gets executed.

I thought .get would just return a simple string.
What am I missing?

thanks for any help!

Comment: may be there are spaces in the text, can you try `if($.trim(data) == 'ready')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be there are spaces in the text, can you try `if($.trim(data) == 'ready')`

```
$.get('status.php', null, resp, 'text');


function resp(data) {

    console.error(':' + data + ':');

    if($.trim(data) == 'ready') {

        alert(data);               
    }
}
```

Comment: isnt it identical to Sudhir's answer :P maybe you are bit slow

Comment: @NullPoiиteя there are differences.

Comment: @NullPoiиteя may be few second I think... I posted it as a comment first... then moved it as an answer

Comment: ok, stupid me - you are correct! There was actually a line break. However this was not in the echo statement in the php script – is that standard behavior? Now it works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

may be you have extra spaces in your response, try:

```
function resp(data) {
      data = $.trim( data );
      console.error(data);
      if(data == 'ready') {    
           alert(data);               
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

jquery can differentiate between data and a callback, try passing your function as the second argument.

```
$.get('status.php', resp, 'text');
```